# .NET HttpClient Connect To Web Service through VPN

Tags: c#, .net, vpn, dotnet-httpclient

I have an application that needs to communicate with a web server hosted on an external provider. It's been configured to only allow incoming connections from IP addresses that it recognizes.

If I needed to connect when I was working remotely and connected through VPN, I would add routes through a terminal window like `sudo route -n add -net 22.222.222.22/32  192.168.133.1`

I don't want every user that works remotely to have to do this. Can I do something in the application layer to allow a user that connected through the VPN to connect to the remote web server and use the VPN tunnel? It is a C# Winforms application.

Comment: To make it clear, you're saying your application should *not* use the VPN tunnel?

Comment: The application should use the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Could you find a fix for that? I am facing exactly the same issue!

Comment: @LaurentKempé Unfortunately, I never did find a fix. The project got dropped for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all of the users of your app are behind the same firewall? If that's the case, then your network admin should be able to setup the routing for you either on the router directly or on your NAT server. It's also worth noting that, at least at my company, we've always had to add the routing statements twice - one for internal and one for outside over VPN. It would be a massive security vulnerability if an app could modify your computer's routing table so I wouldn't do that.

One more thought - it's possible that your VPN uses a common feature called split tunneling which means that all destinations behind your firewall would go over VPN (and have the associated routing rules applied), but any destinations outside (such as your external provider) are split and instead go straight out without any routing. The only way around this would be to setup a VPN tunnel between your firewall and your external provider (e.g. at my company we've done this with our cloud servers so they are accessible over VPN).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling

Comment: I copied and pasted the command that was meant to be run on Linux. Couldn't find the Windows one. I'm not actually developing a winforms app for Linux. And not all of our users are behind the firewall. We have some that work remotely and run the application on their personal computer while connected to the VPN.

Comment: Right, but they are all going through the same router (i.e. they are behind the same firewall) which is where you want to setup the route statements. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

I could discern in your comments, that you are trying to add a route in a windows environment, but only found a command that works on linux?!

But I actually don't get your drift, and what the result of your application should be.
First of all I'll try to help you adding a route to your routing table with C# on a windows machine. (Server-sided)

I've created a little WinForm with a Button-Control `btnAddRoute` and a Textbox-Control `textBox1` to give you an example:

[image: Adding a new route requires elevation!]
*Adding routes only works as administrator btw*

```
private void btnAddRoute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // route -p add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mask 255.255.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    string netIp = "22.222.222.22";
    string mask = "255.255.255.255";
    string exitIp = "192.168.133.1";
    string arg = String.Format("-p add {0} mask {1} {2}", netIp, mask, exitIp);

    Process p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            FileName = "route",
            Arguments = arg,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII
        }
    };
    p.Start();

    textBox1.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This adds a route with the specified IP's to your routing table, and returns OK! or Failed! depending on if the action was successfully or not.

Is this more or less what you want? Or did I totally amiss?